# How to observe another user activities on webpage

Tags: javascript, user-interaction

I have to create a web page, where all activity of some user will be seen by second user.
Simply, the second user see everything what the first user is doing at his page.

I know, that It is possible using AJAX or Websockets, but I' m interested in simpler solution.

**Do you know any simple solution, which enables to intercept frame of another user?**

I had browsed many pages, but I haven't found satisfactory solution.

I assume that I control the source code of this application.

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: It's surely not meant as such, but this reads like "I already know of two solutions, but I'm too lazy to implement either of them. Could someone give me something on a gold platter?"

Comment: @Juhana While I see your point, one could interpret the question as "am I reinventing the wheel here?".

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mozillas TogetherJS](https://togetherjs.com/).

It is a solution for users interacting with a page together in realtime; it might do what you are trying to achieve.